# What is the answer to questions: present occupation and like or dislike school days correct?

Tags: questions

I have to make questions with the following words are they correct? What could be the answer to the second question?

school days_ like or dislike?

present occupation

do you like or dislike school days?

What is your present occupation?

Comment: What is the problem with the second question? Is it that you do not know the meaning of "occupation"?

Answer (score 1):

Both questions are grammatically correct.

An answer to the second question could be “My current occupation is teaching” or “My present occupation is that of a teacher”. If you find that that sounds too formal and stilted, you can simply reply with “I teach for a living” or “I’m a teacher”.

Note that it is grammatically wrong to say “My current occupation is a teacher” since ‘teacher’ refers to a person, not a job or occupation.

Source: [English forum](http://josecarilloforum.com/forum/index.php?topic=1244.0)